# Build events in C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

I have a post-build event in my C++ Visual Studio 2010 project, which uses command `xcopy`, but when this xcopy return error code (>0), all build failed too and message "build unsuccessfull", how can i turn of error sensetivity in build events?

Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason you want to *ignore* the failed xcopy result?

Comment: Maybe run a batch file instead.

Comment: A post build *is* a batch file.  Use exit /b 0.

Comment: @HansPassant It doesn't matter if the post-build-event exits `0`. When an app is called that generates an error, `signtool` for an easy example, it will exit with a failure unless you use `IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"` or `IgnoreExitCode="true"` or `ContinueOnError="true"`

Comment: Btw, only `Command` is required for `Exec`. All but three of the fields take strings: `Command`;`CustomErrorRegularExpression`;`CustomWarningRegularExpression`;`EnvironmentVariables`;`IgnoreExitCode [bool]`;`IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat [bool]`;`LogStandardErrorAsError [bool]`;`Outputs`;`StandardErrorImportance`;`StandardOutputImportance`;`StdErrEncoding`;`StdOutEncoding`;`Timeout`;`ToolExe`;`ToolPath`;`WorkingDirectory`. Src: `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild\Microsoft.Build.CommonTypes.xsd"` as well as the one in `bin`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Exec` task's `IgnoreExitCode`:

```
<Target Name="MyAwesomePostBuildTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec IgnoreExitCode="true" Command="xcopy etc. etc." />
</Target>
```

Comment: Didn't know this even existed. Is this configurable as a property from the UI (I don't have my VS running in front of me; on a different machine).

Comment: I do not know.  I avoid using the IDE to edit project files because it so loves to mangle them.

Comment: Then you've likely done your fair share of mangling indeed =P. I saw a mention of it just now back to VS 2005; does it seem consistent through 2012? I may have a genuine use for it and am just curious if it is reasonably reliable. (oh, and +1. perfect fit for the question)

Comment: The technique is reliable and documented, yes.

Comment: Swap out `IgnoreExitCode="true"` for `IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"` when you want to have control of how the event will exit, and don't forget about `ContinueOnError=` being set to `"true"` or `"false"` depending on your needs. Basically, apps that generate failures will only fail the event if you let it. You can just manually `exit /b 0` or even `exit 0` at the end of the event, or wherever is most appropriate for your command(s) to end on success.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the failure result of (almost) any batch CMD by appending `|| exit /b 0` to the end of the command.  Example:

`del somefile.txt || exit /b 0`

In this way batch files work a bit like C.  You can do && to conditionally run a command when the previous command succeeds, and || to run a command when the previous command fails.

`exit /b 0` tells the CMD processor to exit the script and set the errorlevel to zero (0).  Never forget to include the /b switch!  Without it, CMD will exit the calling script as well as the current script which is rarely, if ever, the desired behavior.

I use this trick from the Visual Studio IDE, so there's no need to do low-level project hacking.  And it fits on one line, which is also convenient from the IDE.

Another useful trick is silencing the command, by the way:

`xcopy srcfile destfile 1>nul 2>nul || exit /b 0`

`1` is stdout, and `2` is stderr.  Windows suite of shell programs are notoriously inconsistent with regard to which output they might use, so I generally just pipe both or pipe neither.